# Android: Is there any way to to cast ImageView to RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to cast and `ImageView` to `RelativeLayout`. Because the `RelativeLayout` is the parent View and there are many images as Child views in this. So I have written code to download image and set it to the Image view. But the case here i want to set this downloaded image as background of the parent view that is of `RelativeLayout`.

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.bg_image);
           ImageView bgImage=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bground_image);

downloader = new ImageDownloader();
         downloader.download(item.imageurl(), bgImage);
```

/// Image is now set in bgImage//
    ///////// Now here i want bgImage to be set as a background of layout////

thankx in advance

Answer (score 2):

To set a background image you can use something like

```
layout.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(<your image>));
```

Comment: bgImage is not a type of resources so it will not work

Comment: You can also use any Bitmap made by BitmapFactory (it can decode jpg, png from files or others streams)

Answer (score 0):

No this is simply not possible because these are completely different types.

You can cast any RelativeLayout or ImageView to View, because this is the base class for all views.

But what you are trying to do should be a little different. You can inflate the ImageView from the RelativeLayout because it is the parent.

I will add a code snippet later.

Update :

```
// First inflate your layout
View layout = (View)findViewById(R.layout.relativelayout);
// Then inflate the imageview from the layout
ImageView imgview = (ImageView)layout.findViewById(R.id.bground_image);

// Then do your download logic with the imageview
downloader = new ImageDownloader();
downloader.download(item.imageurl(), imgview);
```

Let me know if this works ;).

Comment: yes exactly you are right thanks and  please add the code snippet just to get an idea.

Comment: My question is still unclear. I want to set the image downloaded as background image of `RelativeLayout` not as background of `ImageView`

Comment: Well, you are giving an ImageView type variable to the downloader. Then make sure it accepts an RelativeLayout and then do the logic in you downloader.

Answer (score 0):

Best way I think is take one another Imageview with same dimensions as Relativelayout(may be fill parent) with **scaletype fitxy** and set the image to this as you are doing lazy loding and cant pass that relativelayout to loader....... this fitxy will work as background of parent layout

Or another way is change your downloder code to accept relative layout and set background once you have the image

Answer (score 0):

Just add the image to the background of `RelativeLayout`. It should be 1st in order to be behind all other views in the layout. Then you can use it with code that expects an `ImageView`.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/an_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <!--other views go here-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

And no, you can't cast between these types, obviously. This is Java!